# Which versions of Magento include search suggestions?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community, catalogsearch, search

I am using Magento Community Edition version 1.8, I am following these instructions in order to enable suggestions/autocomplete:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuring-catalog-search .

But I don't see the "enable search suggestions" drop down in my admin panel? Is this not an option in my edition or has it moved?

Answer (score 1):

This option is available in Magento Go and not in the Community Edition of Magento.

Though there is an autosuggestion already enabled in Magento Community Edition too. You can check on your storefront. It will only show the title of the product with the quantity available.

Moreover, There are some free extensions available on Magento Connect which will provide you better auto-suggestion. Link of one of them which I use is [Search Auto Suggestion](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-autocomplete-and-suggest-by-instantsearch.html)

Comment: Thanks Dex. Could you please expand on "There is an autosuggestion already enabled in Magneto Community Edition?" I am unable to see any evidence on the front of backend of my CE install.Thanks

Comment: http://speedstop.greetingtoindia.com/

Comment: Is that 1.8 CE? Any idea why I would not be seeing it?

Comment: @Sam: Its available in all versions of Magento.. i have worked from 1.5 till 1.9... It is available...

Comment: Is there an on/off option for it anywhere? I'm not seeing it on front or backend.

Comment: no there is no option to disable auto-suggest from admin but it can be done tweaking code.

Comment: Any ideas on why it would not be working on my build?

Comment: if you can share the link then i can check